# Is there a way to change the location of an existing Notification Hub from the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

When creating a new *Notification Hub* through Azure Portal (Web), it is possible to select the desired location for the Hub (*e.g. East US*).

Is there any way to update that location once the Notification Hub is created? I can't seem to find any way to do that via the UI.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'd have to delete it then recreate it in another data center.

Comment: region ;) you cant control which datacenter it is being created in (inside the region)

Comment: ^^ Doh! You are right - bad terminology on my part.